# Object behaviour changed after assigned the variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have received a query/argument **(matchQuery)** from the client side through API.
When I console this **request.query.matchQuery**.on the server side it gives me **{"count":{"$gt":1}}** this is good for me.

when I assign this argument on the other variable like this

```
var aggregateQuery = {
             $match: request.query.matchQuery
 }
```

and now I console **aggregateQuery** its returns

> { '$match': '{"count":{"$gt":1}}' }

its behavior gets changed. But I don't want to single quotes on the right
side.

**OUTPUT**

> { '$match':{"count":{"$gt":1}}}
>
> OR
>
> { $match:{"count":{"$gt":1}}}
>
> OR
>
> { $match:{count:{$gt:1}}}

Comment: The `'` tells you that it's a string. Try `JSON.parse`

Comment: @CertainPerformance tried"JSON.parse "code break it returns ***InternalError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2***

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"count":{"$gt":1}}')` works for me.

Comment: @CertainPerformance its work for me But my question is that when I assign this ***{"count":{"$gt":1}}*** into another variable like var aggregateQuery = {
             $match: {"count":{"$gt":1}}
 }
and I print its got changed.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to correct data that receive in **serialized JSON** is to parse it. JavaScript has JSON global object for facilitate JSON conversion and applied in application.

in your case evidence shows that request that came from client is like this:

```
  "{\"count\":{\"$gt\":1}}"
```

but in your framework changed to **STRING**

```
   typeof('{"count":{"$gt":1}}')    ==>   'string'
```

that is not object

for use **request.query.matchQuery** as java script object your may convert it to JavaScript Object. for more details refer to below example:

```
var aggregateQuery = {
   $match: JSON.parse(request.query.matchQuery)
}
```

#### Notice:

If you are not in **STRICT MODE** by adding

```
 "use strict"
```

you can execute your code with

```
 eval( code to be execute )
```

for examlpe

```
 eval(`var e = { '$match':` + '{"count":{"$gt":1}}' + `}`)
```

Comment: I tried ***var aggregateQuery = {
   $match: JSON.parse(request.query.matchQuery)
}*** code break it returns ***InternalError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position***

Comment: client request most in **JSON** format that is <pre>'{"count":{"$gt":1}}'</pre>. If **request.query.matchQuery != JSON** it may break and need refactor. Take console again and check your input. syntax is correct, the input most checked again.